# How do i implement a type function

Tags: asp.net

I have created a function which return the value according to the specified type.

Code:

```
private T FindCellValue<T>(GridViewRow grdRow, string cntName)
        {
            var currColType = grdRow.FindControl(cntName);
            object val = currColType;
            if (currColType is HiddenField)
            {
                val = ((HiddenField)currColType).Value;
            }
            if (currColType is TextBox)
            {
                val = ((TextBox)currColType).Text;
            }
            if (currColType is HtmlInputText)
            {
                val = ((HtmlInputText)currColType).Value;
            }
            if (currColType is DropDownList)
            {
                var selectedItem = ((DropDownList)currColType).SelectedItem;
                val = new string[] { selectedItem.Text, selectedItem.Value };
            }
            if (currColType is RadDateTimePicker)
            {
                val = ((RadDateTimePicker)currColType).SelectedDate;
            }

            if (!(val is Control || val is WebControl || val is HtmlInputControl) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(val)))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            return (T)val;
        }
```

This code fails many time while typecasting . How do i implement it efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

If T does not match control's value,
What error handling do you need? Return default(T) or throws exception?

At least check

```
if (currColType is DropDownList)
{
    if (typeof(T) != typeof(string[]))
        return default(T); //or throw exception
}

if (currColType is RadDateTimePicker)
{
    if (typeof(T) != typeof(DateTime))
        return default(T); //or throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic types are used to reuse your code and avoid runtime casting cost but in your case its not the case. so a simple function which return an object can be used in this context.you can then in your calling function type cast it to your desired type.

For error handling:
If you type cast your object as 
(type)Object if type casting is not succesful it will return a invalidcastexception so you can check for the same.

you can also use as operator for type casting and check for the null value it will be faster then above method.